# Deleting or hiding features in QGIS in one layer based on the value of the feature in another layer

Tags: qgis, features, masking

I have two tiff-tiles which are maps of the exact same area:

- One of them displays the height of each cell in the area while
- the other displays an identification number of the same cells.

What I was hoping to do was to be able to do in QGIS was to mask or hide cells in the height map by using the values in the identification map.

For example, to hide all height cells where the corresponding identification number equals 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the raster calculator and make a formula like the following:

```
if (identification_number@1 = 1, 0, elevation_raster@1)
```

this computes a new Raster with the original values from your height raster, only the cells where your identification_raster will be 1 will be 0 or any other value insertet into the formula in True case.